# spacemacs search and replace - rebind keys to emulate classic emacs

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs

I started using Spacemacs on a Mac recently and to my horror discovered the M-% doesn't bind to query replace, but takes a screenshot instead.  How can I reconfigure Spacemacs to behave like classical Emacs?

Comment: I use neither Spacemacs nor a Mac but I would imagine that your window manager is consuming the key presses before Spacemacs ever sees them.  Can you disable the screenshot binding or bind it to other keys?

Comment: @loris  That was it, thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe you have to give information about what you did? What kind of window manager you were using, What is the solution is exist etc  so others can also benefit from it.
Answering your question it's always nice.